# Why does this stylesheet get included in Rails development and not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

In my layout application.html.haml I have

```
- if FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo', status: 'on').count > 0
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'on_off_switch'
```

When I have that record, that stylesheet gets included as expected.

However, in production, on Heroku, the stylesheet doesn't get included.

Even though

```
FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo', status: 'on')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<FeatureSwitch id: 2, status: "on", 
name: "display_demo", description: "", conditions: "", 
created_at: "2014-10-04 17:17:18", updated_at: "2014-10-05 14:44:29">]>

irb(main):002:0> 
  FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo', status: 'on').count

=> 1
```

I tried having the conditional in my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.erb (added the .erb extension) but no format that I used was accepted.

Right now I am forced to always include the stylesheet, regardless of the truth of `FeatureSwitch.where(name: 'display_demo', status: 'on')` so I'd like any good way to address it.

Comment: Have you tried without the conditional? Maybe some problems serving static assets, not even related to the ``if statement``?

Comment: Have you add this file to the list of assets to be precompiled?